# Can query postgresql for column array dimensions? (test if column is int[][]?)

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In postgres, how can I query whether a columns contains int[][] (as opposed to int[]?)

I can query for information about the types of columns:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'mytable'
```

and I see udt_name and data_type jointly provide the base type of the columns. But none of these columns say what the arity of an array column is (arity would be 2 for int[][] and 1 for int[], and zero for int).

Postgres clearly has this information as I can see it if I view a table's schema in pgadmin3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_ndims()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
select 
    array_ndims(array[1,2]) as "int[]", 
    array_ndims(array[[1],[2]]) as "int[][]"

 int[] | int[][] 
-------+---------
     1 |       2
(1 row)
```

The number of dimensions of an array column is stored in the system catalog [`pg_attribute`,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) e.g.:

```
create table test(a int[], b int[][], c int[][][]);

select attname, typname, attndims
from pg_class c
join pg_attribute a on c.oid = attrelid
join pg_type t on t.oid = atttypid
where c.oid = 'test'::regclass
and attnum > 0;

 attname | typname | attndims 
---------+---------+----------
 a       | _int4   |        1
 b       | _int4   |        2
 c       | _int4   |        3
(3 rows)
```

The value of `attndims` reflects the way how the column was declared and may differ from dimensionality of actual values:

```
insert into test values (array[1], array[2], array[3]);

select array_ndims(a) as a, array_ndims(b) as b, array_ndims(c) as c
from test;

 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning that `attndims` is more like a documentation attribute. *Presently, the number of dimensions of an array is not enforced, so any nonzero value effectively means "it's an array".*

Comment: The value of `attndims` reflects the way how the column was declared in `create table`. I think the note in the documentation refers to the fact that in Postgres dimensionality is not forced regardless of how it was declared.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As I said (or at least, intended) values above 1 servers only documentation. Because actual column values' dimensions can differ from it.